# How to sort on several fields at once using ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch implementation via the PHP client (version 8.3) provided here: [github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

At present I am using the sort function to first sort results based on the relevancy score provided for by ElasticSearch itself and then sort on the popularity of a certain record. This does not give the wanted results though. Sorting is done as follows at the present:

```
[
  "index" => "products"
  "body" => [
    "query" => [
      "bool" => [
        "should" => [
          0 => [
            "match" => [
              "title" => [
                "query" => "audi a22"
                "fuzziness" => "2"
                "minimum_should_match" => "1"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    "sort" => [
      "_score" => [
        "order" => "desc"
      ]
      "popularity" => [
        "order" => "desc"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I was thinking of creating some sort of runtime field which would take into account both relevancy (via _score) and popularity and sort them according to that value. That seems overly complex though, does ElasticSearch provide another better solution to this?

I tried the query above and boosting results and sorting them myself using PHP, but I feel like ElasticSearch should probably have what I'm looking for. The query itself gives the most relevant results, but often highly unpopular ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) and the popularity field as the [Field Value factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor), that way you can impact the score of the query results with the popularity value. Whoever is more popular would be more relevant.